# How to suppress this sed in Bash?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
set_bash_profile()
{
    local bash_profile="$HOME/.profile"

    if [[ -w $bash_profile ]]; then
        if (grep 'MY_VAR' $bash_profile 2>&1); then
            sed -i '/MY_VAR/d' $bash_profile
        fi
        echo "export MY_VAR=foo" >>$bash_profile
    fi
}

set_bash_profile
```

Here is the first run:

```
bash-4.1$ ./set_bash.sh
```

No output --which is great! And `cat` shows `export MY_VAR=foo` was appended to the file. But when executing a second time, I want `sed` to silently edit `$bash_profile` without outputting the matching string, like it does here:

```
bash-4.1$ ./set_bash.sh
export MY_VAR=foo
```

Comment: Can you include the output you get when you run this command?

Comment: I just copy-and-pasted and ran that command on my system. It appended the line `export MY_VAR=foo` to my `$HOME/.profile` and produced no output. Show us an entire self-contained script that exhibits the problem. There must be something else going on. [mcve]

Comment: When I remove the `>/dev/null 2>&1` from your command, I get `bash: -c: option requires an argument`, which indicates that you're using `bash -c` incorrectly. In fact, as @Barmar says, you can just do the `echo` command without the two layers you've wrapped around it. But I still don't know why you'd be seeing the output on the console.

Comment: Found the bug! Inside the bigger function block, in the source code, there is a line for a `sed -i` to first delete `MY_VAR` if it existed first. It returns the matching lines although I'm expecting it to be silent. Thank you for the link @KeithThompson. Will see how I can either repost a verifiable snippet, or solve it in the process. Otherwise, might consider asking a new question if applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the output from `grep` on `grep 'MY_VAR' $bash_profile 2>&1`. grep outputs the matched line in your profile:

```
export MY_VAR=foo
```

on stdout. The `2>&1` only forwards stderr to stdout. It's good to use `-q` option with grep. Also the subshell `(...)` around the grep is not needed. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set_bash_profile()
{
    local bash_profile="$HOME/.profile"
    if [ -w $bash_profile ]; then
        if grep -q 'MY_VAR' $bash_profile; then
            sed -i '/MY_VAR/d' $bash_profile
        fi
        echo "export MY_VAR=foo" >>$bash_profile
    fi
}

set_bash_profile
```

Comment: There isn't really any need for the `grep` in the first place. If there's no line that matches, `sed` won't change anything.